# Best way to store data in SQLite: Database with many tables VS many databases?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

I'm storing historical stock data for 200 stocks (each stock with ~1 GB of data).  And will be adding about 1 MB of data per day to each stock.

SQLite allows for very large database file sizes, but I'm wondering if as the file size grows, the database's performance will suffer?

Should I keep database file sizes small (~1GB) by using a separate database for each stock?  OR should I just set up one LARGE database (~200GB) with a separate table for each stock?

Comment: One large database with one table would be better, as long as you index it properly. Both of your proposed approaches are not how things are typically done in relational databases. Sharding should only be done as a last-resort when actually needed. Moving off SQLite for something like Postgres would be a better move at that point, too.

Comment: I would seriously reconsider the choice of SQLite for a 200 Gbyte database.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks.  So one large table with a column for symbol name will be best?  Index it by combining symbol name and datetime?

I picked SQLite because it's not server based.  Was getting tons of file access errors with SQL Server when using it with my C# programs

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm definitely open to suggestions.  I was trying to avoid server based database engines because of my problems with SQL Server

Comment: It seems unlikely SQL Server was the cause of your issues, given that it runs places like this website that get [billions of hits a month](https://stackexchange.com/performance). It's also unlikely that SQLite will fix whatever issue you've been having. I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Not that SQL Server was the problem, but over my head.  Could run it fine from SSME, but too many access issues when trying within Visual Studio.  Never had problem with using MS Access DB within my C# programs.